# Proxmox VE Open vSwich configuration?

Tags: proxmox, openvswitch

I am using Proxmox VE 3.3 (which I like very much and have been using for a few years), but cannot seem to make open vSwitch work as per below.

I am having trouble getting Open vSwitch working. I want to use it since the final environment consists of many VLANS which are subject to change, so Open vSwitch would make this much easier.

I have a proxmox installation on a small test network. At first I had the box working fine using a bond of eth0+1 via the standard linux networking model. So I tried breaking down that and using open vswitch instead. I read the proxmox guide, even copied their example confg and changed it, but I just cannot get it to work.

So for testings sake, I have gone back to a single port trunk on the cisco switch and am just trying to get Open vSwitch working with eth0 as my physical port, a single bridge and an internal port for host connectivity.

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces config, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto vmbr0
allow-ovs vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
ovs_type OVSBridge
ovs_ports eth0 vlan10

allow-vmbr0 vlan10
iface vlan10 inet static
ovs_type OVSIntPort
ovs_bridge vmbr0
ovs_options tag=10
ovs_extra set interface ${IFACE} external-ids:iface-id=$(hostname -s)-${IFACE}-vif
address 172.16.1.199
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.1.254
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding my own answer to this question as I have managed to get Open vSwitch working since posting this.

It is important to use the version of Open vSwitch from the proxmox PVE repository and not the standard open vswitch debian repo.

On top of this, for some reason proxmox doesn't seem to recognise the interfaces as Open vSwitch type if you manually create the config in the network/interfaces file. Therefore I recommend using the GUI to build the config.